# setting NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I set a NSString variable in a method, but when I go to retrieve that variable it is null??

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"

@implementation FourthViewController

@synthesize Username,Password,test;

NSString *usName;
NSString *pWord;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gmail.delegate=self;
    NSString *url= [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [gmail loadRequest:requestObj];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {
    usName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('Email').value='%@'",Username];
    [gmail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:usName];
     pWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('Passwd').value='%@'",Password];
    [gmail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:pWord];
    [gmail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"clicked();"]; 
}

-(void)getUserName:(NSString *)uName
{
    [[Username alloc] init];
    Username = uName;
    NSLog(@"USERNAME: %@",Username);
}

-(void)getPassword:(NSString *)pWord
{
    self.Password = pWord;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the following method?

```
-(void)getUserName:(NSString *)uName
{
    [[Username alloc] init];
    Username = uName;
    NSLog(@"USERNAME: %@",Username);
}
```

If so, your code is wrong. It should be:

```
-(void)getUserName:(NSString *)uName
{
    self.Username = uName
    NSLog(@"USERNAME: %@",Username);
}
```

<strike>On another note, why don't you just log the passed `uName`? ie,</strike>

```
-(void)getUserName:(NSString *)uName
{
    NSLog(@"USERNAME: %@",uName);
}
```

EDIT: I just realized what you're trying to do.

Comment: That did not fix it, but thanks for the help. What I am trying to do is get the user name and password from another class and put it in the username and password text box of the website. Once I try to access it in the webViewDidFinishLoad it is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)getUserName:(NSString *)uName
{
    self.Username = uName;
    NSLog(@"USERNAME: %@", self.Username);
}
```

The proper release should be handled by how you declared the property, but you didn't include that, so I don't know for sure.